# Can the recordsToSave property of CKModifyRecordsOperation object be safely used in its modifyRecordsCompletionBlock

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cloudkit, ckmodifyrecordsoperation

Suppose I start a saveOperation using a CKModifyRecordsOperation object.  Can I safely assume that the recordsToSave of the object will store the list of records given at start when I access it within the modifyRecordsCompletionBlock that is executed after the operation completes.

I would assume so, but then I saw this line in the Apple doc (basically not sure what they mean by "initial":   The initial contents of the array are set to the records you specified in the initWithRecordsToSave:recordIDsToDelete: method. You can modify this array as needed before executing the operation.

If there are rare circumstances where it can change, then I want to go another way in my retry logic.

**EDIT added code**

```
   CKModifyRecordsOperation *saveOperation = [[CKModifyRecordsOperation alloc] initWithRecordsToSave:recordsToSave recordIDsToDelete:nil] ;
saveOperation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = completionBlock ; //see completion block definition below
[self.publicDatabase addOperation:saveOperation] ; 

[self.OperationQ addObject: saveOperation] ; //Saved in Q for later retrieval
```

completionBlock is defined as

```
  ^(NSArray *savedRecords, NSArray *deletedRecordIDs, NSError * operationError){
 if(operationError)
 {
    DDLogError(@"Save of Touch event records failed with error %@",operationError) ;
    //Retry, can I do this and safely assume first record retrieved here is the first record I inserted into original recordsToSave array

    CKRecord *cardinalRecord = self.OperationQ[0].recordsToSave[0] ;

     //Read a field from it to decide how to handle retry (e.g: retry after delay if important set of records, don't retry if not etc)..
 }
 else
 {
   //Handle success case
 }
}
```

Comment: Your question would greatly benefit from some relevant code. Show code demonstrating what you are asking.

Comment: I added some code in the edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you added to the question, it seems that you wish to retrieve the array of records originally passed to the modification operation.

Accessing `self.OperationQ[0].recordsToSave` will certainly give you back the same array passed into `[[CKModifyRecordsOperation alloc] initWithRecordsToSave:recordsToSave recordIDsToDelete:nil]`

The message you reference from Apple's docs simply means that if your code updated the contents of `recordsToSave`, it is safe to make those changes up until you call `addOperation:`.

The operation won't ever change that array. So if you don't change it, then accessing it in the completion block will give you back exactly what you passed in originally.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, thats what I'm trying to do. Didn't want to do a whole bunch of stuff assuming this if it could break in some corner case (making it even harder to debug)!

Comment: Hi rmadddy, one more Q.  Is there any way to access the "CKModifyRecordsOperation object" from its own modifyRecordsCompletionBlock?  I.e something like within the modifyRecordsCompletionBlock, a statement like <get current object whose  completion block I am executing>, gets its recordToSave property...this will avoid me storing the object in a separate array.

Comment: If you declare `saveOperation` and the `completionBlock` in the same scope, then yes.

Comment: Thanks for the response, ready.  I have posted a question on CKQueryOperaton.  if you are an expert on that one too, could you please check it out?

Answer (score 0):

In short No. The list of records you get at the end will be the ones that CloudKit has successfully updated. There is a possibility that it failed to update one or more in which case you need to take appropriate action.

Take a closer look at this apple documentation page https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CloudKit_constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Record_Changed_Error_Keys

Which details the sort of scenarios that you need to think about.

Comment: I am not referring to the savedRecords that is received as an argument to the completion block. That is the one set to records that could be saved.  I  am referring to the recordsToSave property on the original object. AFAIK, There is nothing in the documentation that says the two will become the save after the object returns.  Are you sure that is the case?  I.e you have seen it happen in practice?

Comment: In truth I have a bit of trouble with this, hitting a bug in CloudKit using objective C. The bug the cursor value returned was incorrect. I don't know if it's been fixed. I would assume so, and yes I am sure it was a bug cause I reported and got a bug number, although that all happened more than a year ago now.